# Functional variation with square of integral

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I have, all-well-behaved vector fields $\vec{A},\vec{J}:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$  and the real function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and a scalar valued function $\rho:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$. $\vec{J}$ does functionally depend on $f$, which I write like $\vec{J}[f]$. For these I have the variational condition:
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta f}\big(\int_\Omega \vec{J}[f]\cdot\vec{A}d\vec{V}\big)^2 =0, $$ with $d\vec{V}=dx\,dy\,dz$ and $\Omega=\Bbb R^3$.

> Does this simplifiy to any simpler expression for $f$?

The question arises in some chemical research context of mine.

Since the integral itself should be $\ne 0$ in general, I suspect 
$$ \frac{\delta \vec{J}[f]}{\delta f}\cdot\vec{A}=0$$ could result. But I am note sure, if I don't make a mistake.

---

I give a concrete example:
\begin{align}
\vec{r}=&(x,y,z)^T \\
r=&|\vec{r}|\\
\vec{A}=&(y,-x,0)^T\\
\vec{J}=&f(\rho(\vec{r}))(-y,x,0)^T\\
\rho(\vec{r})=&\exp{(-r)}\\
f(\zeta)=&\sin(\zeta)\\
\end{align}
Then 
$$ \vec{J}[f]\cdot\vec{A}=-\sin(\exp{(-r)})(x^2+y^2)$$
The question I am interested in is how to choose $f$ in dependence of $\vec{A},\vec{J},\rho$ such that the integral from the first expression becomes extremal.

Comment: How does $J$ depend on $f$ when the domain of $J$ is different from the codomain of $f$? Do you mean that for each $f$, $J$ is a vector field?

Comment: via an inner function $\rho:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ like $f(\rho(\mathbf r))$

Comment: Okay, as it stands I don't really understand the things involved so could you please add some more details? For instance, I don't understand what or where the "inner function" is or comes from.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking: I have added an example that should clarify the general set-up.